# /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gcc

I've just update my MAC OS Mountain Lion's compiler to gcc 4.8.1, the configure & install process is:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

the GCC 4.8.1 was installed completely, but then I found I cannot open my Chrome, as well as several other programs. I've check the error report, the most important information is:

```
Dyld Error Message:
    Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    Referenced from: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

So what should I do to solve this? Recompile GCC with proper architecture? But how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overwritten several system libraries with incompatible versions. You will need to reinstall Mac OS X.

**Don't install software with `--prefix=/usr`.** That prefix is reserved for software distributed with the operating system. Use `/usr/local` for software you install yourself. You may want to try [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) instead once you've reinstalled.

Comment: I'm now trying to rebuild gcc 4.8.1 with --perfix=/usr  --enable-multiarch option and reinstall again, could it be useful? The error message just said found wrong arch..

Comment: No, it's still the wrong version. You will need to reinstall Mac OS X.

Comment: I've reinstalled Mac OS X and all these programs back online again. Thank you for help~~~

Answer (score 0):

Since libstdc is deprecated and removed in iOS12, you need to update your dependencies to use libc++ or manually add libstdc. For manually adding refer this - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255046/2140073)