# can't import torch mac

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to import torch and I'm getting the next problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    import torch._dl as _dl_flags
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_dl.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_dl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_dl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

someone knows how can I solve this?
Thanks:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928586/usr-lib-libstdc-6-dylib-mach-o-but-wrong-architecture)

Comment: How did you install `pytorch`? Does it support MacOS or your version of Python?

Comment: @GregEremeev so I need to format my computer for this?

Comment: @HoriaComan pip install torch torchvision. and I'm using python 2.7 so this is the correct version

Comment: @chengal Sure! Make it quick, before it's too late!

Comment: @GregEremeev why it can be late?

Comment: @chengal are you sure your computer can run this thing? As Greg pointed out, you might be trying to run 64 bit code on a 32 bit machine. If you do `file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_dl.so` what is the output?

Comment: @HoriaComan `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_dl.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64`

Comment: And if you follow [these instructions](https://www.chiefarchitect.com/support/article/KB-01230/determining-if-your-computer-is-32-bit-or-64-bit.html) is your computer a 32 bit or 64 bit system?

Comment: @HoriaComan 64bit

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas

Comment: @HoriaComan ok.. thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that:

```
mkdir test_torch
cd test_torch
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install torch torchvision
python3

>>> import torch
```

Works for me. MacOS 10.13.4, Python 3.6.4

Or like that:

```
mkdir test_torch
cd test_torch
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install torch torchvision
python2

>>> import torch
```

Works for me. MacOS 10.13.4, Python 2.7.10

If you don't need to use `torch` then you can install only torchvision

```
pip install --no-deps torchvision
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.. so i have to delete the 3?

Comment: @chengal I've added the solution for Python2.x. Try it.

Comment: @chengal brew install virtualenv

Comment: `Error: No available formula with the name "virtualenv" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow`

Comment: `Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
These similarly named formulae were found:
pyenv-virtualenv ✔                       pyenv-virtualenvwrapper ✔
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install pyenv-virtualenv ✔
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: @chengal brew install pyenv-virtualenv

Comment: I did it. Installed also pyenv-virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Also, pip install virtualenv. After that you could try commands which are above, in the answer

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/Gal_Chen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (16.0.0)`. this was install' and the commands in the answer still doesn't work

Comment: Then pip uninstall virtualenv && sudo pip install virtualenv

Comment: thank you very much. that worked:) but what is that virtual env? I will need to use this every time that i want to use torch?

Comment: @chengal if it works then mark the answer as a correct answer. You need to understand what vertualenv is and why developers use it. You need to create virtualenv every time when you wanna create a new project to install all Python packages there. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: ok. thank you:) and if I write a python script how can I use torch?

Comment: Why do we need to use a virtual environment? I intend on only using one version of PyTorch. At the very least just get it working first

Comment: @Goldname https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#why-the-need-for-virtual-environments

Comment: @GregEremeev I know, I read that. I am not looking on how to get it working with best practices. I just want it to work right now, installed on the system level, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
brew install libomp
```

should solve the problem