# Xcode 10 GM libstdc++ error, can't run on simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode10, ios12

I am trying to test my apps for iOS 12. I have a iPad only app that works fine under Xcode 9. When I try to compile it for the simulator with Xcode 10 GM, the following warning appears:

```
URGENT: building for iOS Simulator simulator, but linking against dylib (/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib) built for macOS. Note: This will be an error in the future
```

It will build, but when running it crashes with the following message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol ___cxa_guard_acquire in /Users/.... /.... xxx.app because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded.
```

I haven't done anything, it happened on the first try.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can find the solution from the following [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9)

Comment: Thanks, I found out the linker flag's included the '/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib' which was not needed apparently. I removed this from the OTHER_LDFLAGS and now it seems to be fine again..

Comment: Great :) Please upvote the comment if you've got helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

removed  '/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib' from the 'OTHER_LDFLAGS', seems to be fine again.

Comment: where can i find this file?

Comment: Is not the file, but the reference to it I removed. Simply type it in the search window of your project, and you will find the references

Comment: I am using a third party library that depends on this reference,

Comment: @CWilliams did you fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

libstc is removed in iOS 12 and was first deprecated in Xcode 10. You can however manually add this library in Simulator or update your dependency to use libc++.

Refer this link for manually adding these libraries - [libstdc](https://github.com/Kila2/libstdc-.6.0.9.tbd)

Comment: "_Building with libstdc++ was deprecated with Xcode 8 and is not supported in Xcode 10 when targeting iOS_". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9